# TypeInformation for Apache Flink 1.3.2 BatchTableEnvironment's translate method

Tags: apache-flink

I tried a couple of flink translate() functions in Apache Flink 1.3.2: One is from  BatchTableEnvironment and one is from StreamTableEnvironment. The program gave me the errors  and I got lost. The following program throws an Exception when run (don't know what TypeInformation it needs). It just uses the type information that should match exactly what the result needs. But it does not work, any help?  I think I provided all the details...the

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;

/**
 *
 * @author Paul Z. Wu Oct 28, 2017
 */
public class TableEnv {

    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception {
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        BatchTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

        DataSet<WC> input = env.fromElements(
                new WC("Hello", 1),
                new WC("Ciao", 1),
                new WC("Hello", 1));

        tEnv.registerDataSetInternal("abc", input);
        Table table = tEnv.scan("abc");

        Table wordCounts = table
                .groupBy("word")
                .select("word, count.sum as count");
        System.out.println(wordCounts.getSchema());
        DataSet<WC> a = tEnv.translate(wordCounts, TypeInformation.of(WC.class));
        a.print();
    }

    public static  class WC {

        public WC(String word, int count) {
            this.word = word;
            this.count = count;
        }

        public WC() {
        } // empty constructor to satisfy POJO requirements

        public String word;
        public int count;
    }

}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/scala/typeutils/CaseClassTypeInfo
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenUtils$.fieldAccessorFor(CodeGenUtils.scala:236)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.org$apache$flink$table$codegen$CodeGenerator$$generateFieldAccess(CodeGenerator.scala:1654)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.org$apache$flink$table$codegen$CodeGenerator$$generateInputAccess(CodeGenerator.scala:1602)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$23.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:875)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$23.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:874)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.map(ArrayOps.scala:234)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.generateConverterResultExpression(CodeGenerator.scala:874)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.CommonScan$class.generatedConversionFunction(CommonScan.scala:57)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetScan.generatedConversionFunction(DataSetScan.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.BatchScan$class.convertToInternalRow(BatchScan.scala:48)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetScan.convertToInternalRow(DataSetScan.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetScan.translateToPlan(DataSetScan.scala:65)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.translate(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:350)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.translate(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:329)
    at com.att.ariso.TableEnv.main(TableEnv.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.CaseClassTypeInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a runtime library flink-scala.